# Gradle Error In Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

What Can I Do To Fix This:

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException:
```

Could not execute build using Gradle installation

```
C:\Users\avand\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.8-bin\vruqmccc8532n7gr46qavsii8\gradle-1.8
```

Could not execute build using Gradle installation

```
C:\Users\avand\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.8-bin\vruqmccc8532n7gr46qavsii8\gradle-1.8
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to remove '.gradle' folder in home and/or project directories?

Comment: using any file manager

Comment: In applications like Android Studio you can just right click on the folder / file you want and "Delete" them.

Answer (score 0):

***MY SOLUTION = BELOW THE LIST OF SUGGESTED SOLUTIONS***

I have just recently been dealing with this issue over the past hour and "think" i have resolved my issue/problem so far...

So will post here and because of other people searching for this one....

**The above error is the same one i was getting**

After some searching i came across various suggestions, But the problem also seemed fairly generic of the resolutions for other people as varying..

**When was i experiencing this issue???**

Some times i would get this error while compiling/building a project, but it would ALWAYS appear when i was trying to "Run" the project direct to a physical test device. Also a debug & release build worked fine.

The system restart and IDE restarts did work some times but after awhile it had to be another system restart... I hate doing that, i like to restart once a day at most.. The other solutions listed below did not work for me...

The issue itself also seemed to appear around the time if me installing another usb driver for a Nexus 7 and testing with that device.

> **Suggested solutions from Google** (from my bad short term memory)
>
> 1. Restart the Android Studio IDE / Application - *rarely worked*
> 2. Restart the computer itself - *worked most times for a limited time*
> 3. Perform a project rebuild - *error would some times occur during this*
> 4. Perform a ./gradlew clean - *error would some times occur during this*
> 5. Create a new basic / blank project - *same result most times*
> 6. Different Android Device - *table and phone did the same results*
> 7. Restart ADB service - *did not work for me*
> 8. Another Dev Computer - *was to lazy to test this.. to much effort install A-S*
> 9. Delete the projects gradle folder - *this messed mine up / lucky for backups ;)*
> 10. Change the gradle dependency version - "com.android.tools.build:gradle"- *did not work*
> 11. Re-install gradle inside User folder - "shown in error" - *same result*
> 12. Re-install Android Studio - *did not attempt this (yet)*
> 13. Different version of Android Studio - *did not attempt this (yet)*
> 14. And what ever else i tested quickly

Have posted the above just to give people a quick list to save them from a little google keyword refinement

> **AND what ended up working for me so far**
>
> Restarting the PC worked and after a little time the problem comes
>   back, so decided to open my task manager and have a look at what was
>   taking **SYSTEM MEMORY** and noticed Google Chrome was using a fair
>   bit (as it does, but i love it)..So i shut it down along with (a hd
>   movie, email clients and all the other usual stuff i have running) and
>   hit the "Run" button... It worked.... Restored various backups with
>   nothing else running.. It worked...

**So for me, it was system resources!** i was also able to reproduce the problem by loading down my system with plenty of applications in memory.

**EDIT - Following morning**

This morning when i checked the project, it would "Run" fine with no problem, a "Make project" did produce the error and doing a simple "Rebuild project" resolved this again.. Possibly left over cache or something?..

**STILL always relating to system memory**

Even now i still get this fault, most times closing Google chrome does it, also the pages that are loaded in the browser do not have any Java running so i dont think it is a clash there either.

**HARD DRIVE / WRITE & READ SPEED**

I dont think this applies at all, BUT just adding it as a consideration... If all else still fails, try relocating your project to another physical hard drive?? Not another partition..